# ZF2 input validator for required not empty only when not null

Tags: zend-framework2

I'm building a form with input filters and all in Zend Framework 2.  I'm using arrays to configure my inputs and filters and validators.  So, say I have some input:

```
array(
    'name' => 'foo',
    'required' => true,
)
```

On the page, there's some jQuery code that might optionally hide this input.  If it does, it hides and disables the input.  On submit, var_dump on the form data gives `foo => null` (probably because it didn't actually submit in the post data and so the form input is never given a value).  If the input is not hidden and not filled out then on submit it has `foo => string '' (length=0)`.

I want to require the input to have a value if the input is used.  So, are there some settings I can add to my config array that will allow null to pass validation, but reject the empty string value? Or do I need to write a custom validator?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you ought to use NotEmpty validator.

```
$inputFilter = new \Zend\InputFilter\InputFilter ();
$inputFilter->add ([
  'name' => 'foo',
  'validators' => [
    [
      'name' => 'not_empty',
      'options' => [
        'type' => 'string'
      ]
    ]
  ]
]);

$form->setInputFilter ($inputFilter);
```

Comment: For the sake of other readers, the key here is that if you don't specify your own not_empty validator, a default one is created that is more limiting.  I eventually got my use-case to work.  A couple other keys points here was that I needed to still specify the required attribute (otherwise it seems to assume that it is required?).  Also, I had a StringLength validator on there as well, and that had a problem when the input was null, so I had to drop that.  Haven't investigated whether I can make StringLength ok with a null value yet.